# Hide columns depending on checkbox state with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a fieldset where I created a simple checkbox:

```
$form['my_fieldset']['my_checkbox'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('my title'),
    '#default_value' => 1,
    '#disabled' => FALSE,
);
```

Then, in other fieldset, I have a tableselect with these columns:

- slot1
- slot2
- slot3

The data for these columns is as below:

```
'slot1' => array(
    'data'=> array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Slot1',
        '#title_display'=> 'invisible',
        '#default_value'=> '',
        '#value' => 'slot1',
        '#options' => $my_options,
        '#name' => 'slot1',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('update-slot1')),
    ),
),
'slot2' => array(
    'data'=> array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'Slot2',
        '#title_display'=> 'invisible',
        '#default_value'=> '',
        '#value' => $emulator_data['slot2'],
        '#options' => $cards_available,
        '#name' => 'slot2[' . $emulator_data['container'] . ']',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('update-slot2')),
    ),
),
'config' => array(
    'data'=> array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'config title',
        '#title_display'=> 'invisible',
        '#default_value'=> '',
        '#value' => 'config',
        '#options' => $my_options,
        '#name' => 'config',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('update-config')),
    ),
),
```

What I need is to hide 'slot1' and 'slot2' columns if the checkbox is checked and hide the 'config' column if it's unchecked, using javascript.

Comment: Use `'#states'`. See https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states

Comment: Thanks leymannx, didn't know about that! From what I saw, I can hide the select elements but how to hide the column as a whole?

Answer (score 1):

`#states` is a good JavaScript only approach to hiding simple markup, but sometimes we need to modify the render array itself

To add/remove form elements or complex render arrays based on feedback, you can do so by checking the value of `$form_state['values']['my_fieldset']['my_checkbox']` in a condition around your table column logic. Also wrap the other_fieldset with a div defined in #prefix and #suffix that has that wrapper id.

```
if (isset($form_state['values']) && $form_state['values']['my_fieldset']['my_checkbox']) {
  // Add slot1/slot2 columns here.
}
```

Then add an [AJAX/AHAH](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#ajax) to the checkbox element:

```
$form['my_fieldset']['my_checkbox'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('my title'),
    '#default_value' => 1,
    '#disabled' => FALSE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'my_module_form_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'other-fieldset-id-wrapper',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'slide',
    ),
);
```

Then implement a function to return the form element you want to replace. Note that you do *not* modify the form/form_state here and modifying the form will have no effect. However the value of the checkbox will be stored in form_state values when the form is re-rendered.

```
  function my_module_form_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
    return $form['other_fieldset'];
  }
```

Comment: I already use jquery to color the rows of my table. I think the best solution for this would be to use jquery. Can someone guide me on how to accomplish this? About #states, I get the table data from a function so I think that I can't use that in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure how coloring rows has anything to do with rendering columns?

Comment: the answer is that it has nothing to do besides the fact that I was explaining that I'm using jquery to color the rows, so maybe I can use also jquery to show/hide the columns.